# Can I apply a GTK+ theme to the latest version of GDM? if so, how? (specific to ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: gnome, 16.04, themes, gdm, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to apply a GTK theme to GDM. In my searches for an answer I have seen a couple of times that GDM has discontinued theme support, but it seemed as though that was referring to themes specific to GDM, rather than general gtk themes.

I've already attempted a couple of things:

- I had read you can customize gdm through Ubuntu tweak, so I followed these instructions: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-ubuntu-tweak-in-ubuntu-16-04/ unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do much of anything with it
- I modified "greeter.dconf-defaults" under the GDM directory in /user/share where it specifically mentions gtk themes with nano ([screen-cap of the file and its location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIgvo.png)) though I'm not positive I have the syntax correct
- I looked for a graphical way to do it and I found [GDM3Setup](https://www.github.com/Nano77/gdm3setup) but it seems it doesn't support Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the Software app won't install the .deb for Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`

You can restart GDM by running `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

Note that running that command will immediately end all of your graphical logged in sessions so save your work first.

Source: `/usr/share/doc/gdm3/README.Debian`

Comment: well, I managed to break everything and get a low graphics mode error by not editing it right, but I have now adjusted my syntax, and it is now starting GDM properly, but it still does not seem to have adjusted the appearance http://imgur.com/a/iG88u have I formatted my edit correctly?

Comment: I now tested with a GTK theme here and it didn't do anything either. However setting 'icon-theme' worked to at least change the icons.